# Share properties between classes

Tags: html, css, web

I have two classes which share properties for example:

```
.divone{ width:10px; height:20px; float:right; cursor:pointer; }
.divtwo{ width:11px; height:10px; float:right; cursor:pointer; }
```

As you can see, both classes share properties: "float" and "cursor". How can I declare both properties in a same class and then apply it to both classes? Kind of like this:

```
.sharedproperties{ float:right; cursor:pointer; }

.divone{ width:10px; height:20px; (+ .sharedproperties)}
.divtwo{ width:11px; height:10px; (+ .sharedproperties)}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call them in your html file like that :

```
<div class="sharedproperties divone"><!-- Some content here --></div>
```

or

```
<div class="sharedproperties divtwo"><!-- Some content here --></div>
```

And your CSS file would be :

```
.sharedproperties{
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.divone {
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
}
.divtwo {
  width:11px;
  height:10px;
}
```

Comment: It works but, Is there any way I can do this only in CSS? I mean, adding properties declared in a class to other class. Thanks mate.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I always saw everyone doing like that. Look here : https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Multiple classes in your html is the proper way to do it. If for some unexplainable reason that's an issue, you can use a CSS preprocessor like Sass to extend selectors into other selectors, but this can become a mess very quickly. Multiple classes is really what you should be doing.

Comment: You won't have better answer because this is the best !

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add extra classnames in the mark-up you can use a comma in your CSS to apply rules to several selectors:

```
.divone, .divtwo { float:right; cursor:pointer; }
.divone{ width:10px; height:20px; }
.divtwo{ width:11px; height:10px; }
```